# Spring boot: InternalResourceViewResolver not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I spent several hours trying to use `InternalResourceViewResolver` in order to append prefix and suffix to html views.

My views located under `static/pages/` and by Spring docs, folder `static` is considered to be one of defaults for static content. So, I could access profile page by `pages/profile.html`. But what I really want to have is `profile` instead of `pages/profile.html`.

I've tried several answers, but that does not work, like:

```
    @Bean
public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}
```

and adding

```
    @Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

Still does not work properly. **By adding any suffixes or prefixes I could not found page on any path**. I am starting to get 404 on `pages/profile.html`, but it also does not appear on other urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need add your own custom configuration like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/jsp");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Then you can inspect all your beans via "http://localhost:8080/beans"

And you can verfity is it using the custom configured bean:

```
{

    "bean": "defaultViewResolver",
    "scope": "singleton",
    "type": "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver",
    "resource": "class path resource [io/cloudhuang/web/WebMvcConfig.class]",
    "dependencies": [ ]

}
```

But the eaiest way should be config it in the `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=
spring.mvc.view.suffix=
```

For `application.yaml`

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: templates/
      suffix: .jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot you actually don't need to declare your own InternalResourceViewResolver. Boot declares it for you, and you can just add a couple of properties to your application.properties file. E.g. in your case these would be:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```